# entity Framework Seeding related data

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to seed one to many data elements in the seed method of Entity Framework.

```
        context.AddressTypes.AddOrUpdate(
          p => p.Name,
          new AddressType { Name = "Original" },
          new AddressType { Name = "Shipping" },
          new AddressType { Name = "Billing" }
          );

        context.Addresses.AddOrUpdate(
          a => a.Address1,
          new Address { Address1 = "123 West Main", 
          City = "Hannibal", 
          Region = "MO", 
          PostalCode = "12345", 
          Country = "USA", 
          Type = new AddressType { Id=1 } }
          );
```

How do I add one of the three address types to the address object I am seeding? If I do it the way I have shown it creates a new object in the AddressTypes table.

Comment: Try inserting context.SaveChanges(); between your 2 steps.

Comment: I still get a new addresstype instead of it using the navigation property.

Comment: Do you have AddressTypeId exposed in Address? Otherwise, you could do var Original = context.AddressTypes.Find(1); and set Type = Original

Comment: That is sort of what I have been doing now but it feels cludgy

Comment: if you define a local var address = new Adress {..., Type = adressTypelocal} the fixup will add the AdressType